# Ability to install prerequisites without adding entry in ARP

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I'm looking for a workaround or a solution for the common issue of installing prerequisites without adding entry in ARP.
When a .NET package is successfully installed as a prerequisite for our Burn bootstrapper application, and the user cancels the install, the bootstrapper package is still listed in the Add/Remove programs.

I know there is [another quistion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32559837/wix-managed-bootstrapper-installing-net-framework-and-adding-entry-in-add-remov) and an open [feature request](https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/4822), but I haven't found a workaround for this.

Comment: Not really an answer: I don't think that the .NET framework is something that should be hidden in the ARP. I can imagine hiding your product MSIs from the ARP, but if you installed a 3rd party product, the user should know about it.

Comment: I agree with jbudreau, I've never seen this as a common issue when applied to common redistributables like .NET and VC++ runtimes. In any case, this is neither a WiX nor Windows Installer question. The issue means looking at the docs for installing the (or any) runtime and seeing if it supports a command line option to suppress ARP/Programs&Features, and if they don't then you may be looking for a hack of some kind to do it. If there is a command line option, use Burn features that let you specify it.